# How can I align form elements when using Bootstrap's form-horizontal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue aligning a select dropdown and a button with Bootstrap. Here's a picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWo5k.png]

Here's the code, more or less:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="." method="GET" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="id_location">Location</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            {% render_field form.location class='form-control' data-size='10' %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map_modal">Map</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I get the Map button to line up with the select dropdown?

Comment: Seems to work with base BS CSS (http://www.bootply.com/117059). You might inspect to see if there is margin being applied to one of your elements or containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. The problem was that I had some generic code that output an unordered list of possible form errors above the select textbox. The problem was that if there were no errors, the code to create the unordered list would still be generated, but the list would be empty. This would throw off spacing.

See [this code](http://www.bootply.com/117087) for a concrete example.

All I had to do was first check to see if there are errors before creating that unordered list. So now, the unordered list won't appear unless there are errors.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 3):

Is it okay if you change your markup? If yes then try this.

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/117060)**

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control" >Location</label>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Map</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Solid suggestion, but I ended up figuring it out. The spacing was thrown off due to an small error I made.