# Inline a bootstrap form?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have a form but the form is not inlined:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>


<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Vrsta</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">nafta</option>
      <option value="2">biodizel</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Appended Input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="appendedtext">Kolicina</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="appendedtext" name="appendedtext" class="form-control" placeholder="uptrebljena kolicina" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">kg</span>
    </div>
    <p class="help-block">preostalo 22l</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

How can I inline this form?

I tried with:

```
<form class="form-inline">
```

but that doesn't work. What is the problem here?
I also tried to make three `col-md-4` columns, but again I can't align them with the button.

Comment: Here is a similar **[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053989/how-can-i-align-form-elements-when-using-bootstraps-form-horizontal/22054163#22054163)** which I answered with an example.

Comment: FYI, you should use [Bootply](http://bootply.com) for bootstrap questions

Comment: thanks that works for me, i fin on bootly